# How can I design this corner curve in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Card Corner Curve Design

[image: Card Corner Curve Design]
I want to create a design like this in jetpack compose, but I don't know how to make it.

My main concern is a blue color curve on both corners, which I don't know how to make it. Can someone help to draw me this design?

Comment: consider using [9-patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code as per your usage and implement this on your code.

```
package com.example.myapplication
 
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.CircleShape
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
 
import com.example.myapplication.ui.theme.MyApplicationTheme
 
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyApplicationTheme {
                Column(
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .fillMaxHeight()
                        .padding(20.dp)) {
                    Card(
                        elevation = 4.dp,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp)
                    ) {
                        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                            Text("AB CDE", fontWeight = FontWeight.W700)
                            Text("+0 12345678")
                            Text("XYZ city.", color = Color.Gray)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
                    Card(
                        elevation = 4.dp,
                    ) {
                        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                            Text("AB CDE", fontWeight = FontWeight.W700)
                            Text("+0 12345678")
                            Text("XYZ city.", color = Color.Gray)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I also need that corner blue design, I know how to make the rounded corner, but my main concern is the blue curve design.

Answer (score 0):

Using `quadraticBezierTo` in a `Path` that you draw inside `Modifier.drawBehind` should do.